# How to list configuration file for a specific package on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, configuration, deb

In CentOS, there is this command `rpm -qc packagename`to list all the configuration for a specific package.

```
[spiderman@MyFirstLinuxVM ~]$ rpm -qc sudo
/etc/pam.d/sudo
/etc/pam.d/sudo-i
/etc/sudo-ldap.conf
/etc/sudo.conf
/etc/sudoers
```

Is there any similar command in Ubuntu using `apt`or `dpkg` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the equivalent of rpm -qc PACKAGE\_NAME in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433810/whats-the-equivalent-of-rpm-qc-package-name-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Installed app or not installed app?  If installed, https://askubuntu.com/questions/281853/how-to-list-all-configuration-files-for-an-already-installed-package

Answer (score 0):

I've used cat for finding config files.
for example, lighttpd would look like this

> cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/lighttpd.conffiles